# Java Jsoup output is not formatting the way i want it to

Tags: java, jsoup

I am currently working on a Java program that grabs football scores from soccerstand.com and displays them on screen.

Here is my code up to now:

```
    try{
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.soccerstand.com/").get();
        Elements team1 = doc.select(".team_1");
        Elements team2 = doc.select(".team_2");

        for(Element element: team1){
            System.out.print(element.text()+"\n");
        }

        for(Element element1: team2){
            System.out.println(element1.text());
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My problem is that the output format is incorrect. Currently, the home teams print out in a list which is fine. However, I want the away teams to print directly to the right of the home team they are playing.

Example:
Here are the first three fixtures from the website:

- Barcelona vs Real Sociedad,
- Sivasspor vs Bursaspor
- Comercial FC vs    Ponte Preta

My program will print them out like this:

```
Barcelona //Home Team
Sivasspor //Home Team
Comercial FC //Home Team
Real Sociedad //Away Team
Bursaspor //Away Team
Ponte Preta //Away Team
```

But i want them to print out like this:

```
Barcelona vs Real Sociedad
Sivasspor  vs Bursaspor
Comercial FC vs Ponte Preta
```

I hope this is clear and not too confusing.

Can anyone Help?

---

Answer (score 2):

I think you want your loop to be:

```
for (int i=0; i<team1.size; i++)
{
   System.out.println(team1.get(i) + " vs " + team2.get(i));
}
```